# insert rows with next 10 business days to dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

`df` has three columns - `date`, `name`, and `qty`. For each `name` and `date` combination I want to insert `n` rows such that `name` is repeated in these next `n` rows but `date` is increased by 1 business day and `qty=nan` if that `name` and `date` combination doesn't exist already in `df`.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['abd']*3 + ['pqr']*2 + ['xyz']*1, 'date':[datetime(2020,1,6), datetime(2020,1,8), datetime(2020,2,5), datetime(2017,10,4), datetime(2017,10,13), datetime(2013,5,27)], 'qty':range(6)})
>>> df
  name       date  qty
0  abd 2020-01-06   10
1  abd 2020-01-08    1
2  abd 2020-02-05    2
3  pqr 2017-10-04    3
4  pqr 2017-10-13    4
5  xyz 2013-05-27    5
```

I am not sure how to go about it. Any thoughts/clues. Thanks a lot!

**Desired output** for `n=3`:

```
   name       date  qty
0   abd 2020-01-06   10
1   abd 2020-01-07  nan
2   abd 2020-01-08    1
3   abd 2020-01-09  nan
4   abd 2020-01-10  nan
5   abd 2020-01-13  nan
6   abd 2020-02-05    2
7   abd 2020-02-08  nan
8   abd 2020-02-09  nan
9   abd 2020-02-10  nan
10  pqr 2017-10-04    3
11  pqr 2017-10-05  nan
12  pqr 2017-10-06  nan
13  pqr 2017-10-09  nan
14  pqr 2017-10-13    4
15  pqr 2017-10-16  nan
16  pqr 2017-10-17  nan
17  pqr 2017-10-18  nan
18  xyz 2013-05-27    5
19  xyz 2013-05-28  nan
20  xyz 2013-05-29  nan
21  xyz 2013-05-30  nan
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output using this data?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ScottBoston. I have added desired output for `n=3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
from functools import reduce

n = 3
new_index = (
    df.groupby("name")
    .apply(
        lambda x: reduce(
            lambda i, j: i.union(j),
            [pd.bdate_range(i, periods=n + 1) for i in x["date"]],
        )
    )
    .explode()
)
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(new_index.reset_index(), names=["name", "date"])
df_out = df.set_index(["name", "date"]).reindex(midx).reset_index()
df_out
```

If `explode` cannot be used:

```
from functools import reduce

n = 3
new_index = (
    df.groupby("name")
    .apply(
        lambda x: reduce(
            lambda i, j: i.union(j),
            [pd.bdate_range(i, periods=n + 1) for i in x["date"]],
        )
    )
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .stack()
    .reset_index(level=0)
    .rename(columns={0:'date'})
)
df_out = new_index.merge(df, how='left', on=['name', 'date'])
df_out
```

Output:

```
   name       date  qty
0   abd 2020-01-06  0.0
1   abd 2020-01-07  NaN
2   abd 2020-01-08  1.0
3   abd 2020-01-09  NaN
4   abd 2020-01-10  NaN
5   abd 2020-01-13  NaN
6   abd 2020-02-05  2.0
7   abd 2020-02-06  NaN
8   abd 2020-02-07  NaN
9   abd 2020-02-10  NaN
10  pqr 2017-10-04  3.0
11  pqr 2017-10-05  NaN
12  pqr 2017-10-06  NaN
13  pqr 2017-10-09  NaN
14  pqr 2017-10-13  4.0
15  pqr 2017-10-16  NaN
16  pqr 2017-10-17  NaN
17  pqr 2017-10-18  NaN
18  xyz 2013-05-27  5.0
19  xyz 2013-05-28  NaN
20  xyz 2013-05-29  NaN
21  xyz 2013-05-30  NaN
```

How it works:

First import reduce from functools to use [pd.Index.union](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html#pandas-index-union) to create a single list of dates.  The list of dates is created from [pd.bdate_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html#pandas-date-range), with in groupby for each name.  Convert that list of new_index, and names to a MultiIndex using [pd.MultiIndex.from_frame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html#pandas-multiindex-from-frame).  Use `reindex` after `set_index` on the original dataframe.

Comment: It gives me `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'`. This could be version error - is there a way to bypass it without upgrading version?

Comment: Yep, this is more likely a version issue.  Let's see if we can "explode" that list differently.

Comment: We can try one of these [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218939/6361531).